# Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop Icon failed

Tags: 20.04

[image]

Desktop icons on my ubuntu 20.04 look like this. For example, Software Updater and Ubuntu Software cannot display the correct icons. And others are also different from the default icons of Ubuntu 20.04

Although I tried `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons`. There's nothing changes.
Can you help me?

Comment: I don't see the problem. What icons do you expect to see, and what do you see? Maybe you expect an other theme than the one you have?

Comment: @SorenA "Software Updater" and "Ubuntu Software" are showing generic icons rather than specific icons. I do not immediately see that the others are also different, but then it could be due to using a different icon pack than the default one, Yaru

Comment: Open a terminal and type `ls /usr/bin/*session` and let us know what the output is. It will show what you have installed.

Comment: this is what terminal shows:
/usr/bin/dbus-run-session  /usr/bin/gnome-session-custom-session
/usr/bin/gnome-session